# Apache 320 redirect loop with correct htaccess and virtualhost conf

Tags: linux, ssl, apache2

I am web designer and I manage a VPS Server.

Server is LAMP Ubuntu 18 apache2 PHP 7.4  root index.html

**This page isn’t working test.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Have checked the .htaccess and vhost conf
could not find anything wrong

````
   Status:  302 Found
   Code:    302
   Date:    Mon, 21 Aug 2023 06:07:02 GMT
   Server:  Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
   Location:    https://test.com
   Content-Length:  301
   Connection:  close
   Content-Type:    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1```
````

```
htaccess file :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

```
   vhost file
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.test.com"
   </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please include both the .htaccess and the vhost.conf in your question.

Comment: Is there a vhost file for the port 443 (HTTPS:) as well?

Comment: no
have same vhost for other working websites, they are fine. @
tsc_chazz

Comment: Additionally: Ubuntu 18 is End of Life unless you have paid extended support  - https://ubuntu.com/18-04

Comment: Fixed it. It was in the 443 block of vhost -le-ssl.conf in  sites-available @HBruijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only posted the VirtualHost block for the plain HTTP port, port 80.

There should be a second VirtualHost block (possibly from a different sites-available Include file) for the HTTPS VirtualHost on port 443.

In there you have a redirect from `https://example.com` to `https://example.com` (which results in an endless loop).